# MongoDB random sample based on field (chance)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, random

In the app I'm building I need to randomly get N records from a collection. But the chance of a record to appear in the sample should depend on the `probability` field of that record. The higher the `probability` field value is - the more likely that record will appear in a sample.

Is it possible to handle such functionality using MongoDB aggregation?

Comment: You may want to look into $sample - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/

Comment: @barrypicker, I've looked into sample before. But $sample doesn't have any bias parameter. It just returns kinda normal randomness.

Comment: how big is your collection? is probability an integer or a float? An approach can be duplicating the document (using probablity) and apply $sample. But can be very bad in huge collections.

Comment: MongoDB currently does not support any form of weighting. You will need to find some kind of workaround. For example, if your collection isn't prohibitively large, then you using map-reduce you can generate a random number between 0 and 1 for each document, multiply this value by your `probability`, and store that new value on the document. You can then sort the results by this value in descending order, and then limit the results to `N` documents.